# Not receiving refresh_token from Google OAuth2 second time even though I pass required options

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-signin

I have read many answers in SO for similar question.

Most of them were able to solve it by adding `access_type: "offline"` and `approval_prompt: "force"` while generating Authentication URL.

I tried the same thing as suggested by many answers in SO.

I'm able to receive the `refresh_token` while authenticating for the first time. But, from 2nd time onwards I'm not receiving the `refresh_token`, only `access_token` is passed.

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

After researching for a while I found a workaround.

Instead of `approval_prompt: "force"`, I used `prompt:"consent"` and I'm able to get `refresh_token` everytime.